# How to use nested for loop to draw N*N grid of size*size squares?

Tags: java, image, oop, colors

Using color class to draw random colored squares in a `[][]` array of colors that can be inserted into the grid of `n*n` and each square is `size * size`  also, picture class takes x, y and color parameters.

I have only managed to `drawSquare()` on the grid but need the full grid populated with squares of random color.

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class ColorSquares {
    public static void main (String[]args){
        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); //the n*n grid
        int size = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); // the size * size in a square
        Picture p = create(N, size);
        p.show();
        // Picture p=  Picture(N, size);

        // p.show();
    }
        public static void drawSquare(Picture p, int x0, int y0, int size, Color c)  {
        for (int x = x0; x < x0+size; x++)
            for (int y = y0; y < y0+size; y++)
                p.set(x,y,c);
    }


    /* Create a Picture which is an NxN grid of color squares
     * each square is size*size pixels */
    public static Picture create(int N, int size){
        Picture p = new Picture(N * size, N * size);

       Color[][] createColors = createColors(N);
        // the N represents the number of squares for the row to go through
       for (int r = 0 ; r < N  ; r++) {
           // the N also represents the number of squares the column goes through
           for (int c = 0; c < N ; c++) {
            drawSquare(p,r, c , size, createColors[r][c]);

            // drawSquare.set(r,c, createColors[r][c]);
             p.set(r,c,createColors[r][c]);
         }
        }

        return p ;
    }

    /* Create a two-dimensional NxN array of random Colors*/
    public static Color[][] createColors(int N){
        Color [][] colors = new Color [N][N]; // N*N board
     //   Color ranColor = (Color) generateRandomColor(Color);


        for ( int r = 0 ; r < N ; r++ ) {
            for ( int  c = 0; c < N ; c++) {
            colors[r][c] = generateRandomColor();



            }
        }

        return colors;
    }

    /* Generate a random Color (R,G,B each between 0 and 255) */
    public static   Color generateRandomColor(){

        //int colorValue = 0 + (int)(Math.random() * ((255 - 0) + 1));
       // int  colorValue = (int) Math.random (color);
        //return new  Color( colorValue,colorValue, colorValue);
        int red   = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        int green = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        int blue  = (int) (Math.random() * 256);

        Color randomColor = new Color( red, green, blue );
            return randomColor;
    }

}
```

Comment: sorry but what exactly is your question?

Comment: how can I use the nested for loop to draw an N*N grid and the squares within randomly colored by the createColors[][]. i can only get a single spec in the grid to draw with random colors

Comment: well you seem to be doing so, what is wrong with what you are doing?  I guess that you are changing the color for every pixel though?

Comment: yeah exactly, but I need every pixel within that square to be same color, then the next square to be different random color but all pixels within same and so forth till the grid is populates with N*N squares

Comment: rather than incrementing in steps of `one` increment with something bigger

Comment: public static Picture create(int N, int size){
        Picture p = new Picture(N * size, N * size);

       Color[][] createColors = createColors(N);
        // the N represents the number of squares for the row to go through
       for (int r = 0 ; r < N  ; r+=size) {
           // the N also represents the number of squares the column goes through
           for (int c = 0; c < N ; c+=size) {
            drawSquare(p,r, c , size, createColors[r][c]);

            // drawSquare.set(r,c, createColors[r][c]);
             p.set(r,c,createColors[r][c]);

Comment: that would still not populate the entire grid IDK what i am doing wrong in the create() method